# MySQL just returns empty result set instead of throwing error 1452

Tags: php, mysqli, transactions, insert, foreign-keys

When I try to do an insert into a table with a foreign key constraint that doesn't allow one of the values, it just returns an empty result set although I expected it to throw the error 1452 to perform a rollback. Due to that the execute in php returns true although the dataset was not inserted. My workaround to get the desired behaviour is that I check if the affected row count equals 0 and I throw the exception myself. But nevertheless I would like to know why I get this behaviour and if my workaround could lead to further problems at one point.

UPDATE1:

[diagram of the affected part of the DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrn2V.jpg)

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO service_categories 
            SELECT T1.cat_id, ? 
            FROM category_languages T1 
            INNER JOIN languages T2 ON T1.cat_lang = T2.lang_id 
            WHERE (T2.lang_name_iso3 = ?) AND (T1.cat_title=?)")){
    $stmt->bind_param('iss', $service_id, $service_language_name, $service_category);
    $exec_successful = $stmt->execute();
    if((!$exec_successful) or ($mysqli->affected_rows === 0)){
        //failure: INSERT
        $mysqli->rollback();
    }
}
```

When I try to insert a `service_category` into `service_categories` with a `cat_id` that doesn't exist in `categories` the foreign key constraint prevents the insert from succeeding. That´s what it's supposed to do but `execute()` still returns `true` while `affected_rows` is returning `0`.

UPDATE2:

[sql fiddle of the affected part of the DB](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b005)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your database and the query you run, so we could reproduce the problem?

Comment: Can you provide an sql fiddle?

Comment: @user4035 I tried that, but just got the schema to work. No sql query worked, not even a simple SELECT * FROM categories.

Comment: Please, provide even the unfinished fiddle. It works, you just did something wrong. I'll try to find out, what's wrong.

Comment: Mischa, did you solve the problem? I'll try to help you as soon as I get time today.

Comment: @user4035: No, I didn't solve it yet. I mean, I got the workaround with the manually thrown exception so that everything works so far, but I really would like to know why is happening what's happening ;) By the way, the same insert performing in myphpadmin results also just in an empty result set. PHP shouldn't be the issue though. I really appreciate your help because I am actually pretty much stuck there...